# Working with a Range Variable...syntax

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
Set rFinder = wkEnrollment.Range("EnrollmentIDs")  
With Range(rFinder)
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
```

It errors when I do my `With Range(rFinder)` line.  `rFinder` is dim'd as a `Range`. The error is:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I am not sure of the syntax on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since `rFinder` is already a Range object you should simply use:

```
Set rFinder = wkEnrollment.Range("EnrollmentIDs")  
With rFinder
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
```